# How to interpolate data from unevenly spaced array in Julia?

Tags: julia, interpolation

How can I construct an **interpolate of unevenly spaced data** in Julia, using nearest neighbor interpolation? I took a look at [the documentation](http://juliamath.github.io/Interpolations.jl/latest/control/#Gridded-interpolation-1) and typed the following at REPL:

```
using Interpolations
input = [1.0 60; 1.1 0; 2.0 60; 2.3 0; 4.0 430; 4.05 0]
itp   = interpolate(input[:,1], input[:,2], Gridded(Constant()))
```

Which seemed straightforward to me, but gives:

> ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching
>   interpolate(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1},
>   ::Gridded{Constant})

Do I need to convert the `Array`s to `Vector`s? If so, how? Please tell me there is an easy solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are in an *N*-dimensional space, you should put the coordinates of interpolation "knots" in an *N*-tuple of vectors. In 1-D, this means a 1-tuple like `(x,)` instead of plain `x`:

```
julia> input = [1.0 60; 1.1 0; 2.0 60; 2.3 0; 4.0 430; 4.05 0]
6×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0    60.0
 1.1     0.0
 2.0    60.0
 2.3     0.0
 4.0   430.0
 4.05    0.0

julia> x = input[:, 1];
julia> y = input[:, 2];
julia> itp = interpolate((x,), y, Gridded(Constant()))
6-element interpolate((::Array{Float64,1},), ::Array{Float64,1}, Gridded(Constant())) with element type Float64:
  60.0
   0.0
  60.0
   0.0
 430.0
   0.0

julia> itp(1.01)
60.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But after testing it, I noticed that I was looking for a piecewise interpolation using the *previous* value, similiar to [Matlab's](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant.html#bvh2cy0-Method) `griddedInterpolant(___, 'previous')`. Can this be done as well in Julia?

Comment: I'm not sure such a feature exists in `Interpolation` at the moment. However, it should be fairly easy to implement one. Maybe this would be a welcome PR?

Comment: By PR, you mean "pull request"? It seems that [one already exists](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Interpolations.jl/pull/338), but is still pending...

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Glad to see the feature is in the radar...